# Copy only records that do not exist in the target table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Having two tables (the source and target) intend to copy only the records from the source table that do not exist in the target table (making the comparison with the value of a specific cell in each record).  I thought to do it using arrays, but as I am new in this area, needed help.

Examples:

*Source Table*

**ID    Date    Description**

115 01-Ago  Description1

120 05-Ago  Description2

130 03-Ago  Description5

110 08-Ago  Description4

105 06-Ago  Description6

*Destination Table*

**ID    Date    Description**

130 03-Ago  Description5

110 08-Ago  Description4

I want to add in the target table records from the source table that do not exist in the target table (ID's 115,120,105 in this example). Thank you!

I'm almost there. After consulting some other questions, I need something like this:

Sub Tests()

```
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim tgtLastRow, srcLastRow As Integer
Dim rngTarget, rngSource, cel As Range
Dim Delim As String

Delim = "#"

tgtLastRow = Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
srcLastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set rngTarget = Range("H2:H" & tgtLastRow)
Set rngSource = Range("A2:A" & srcLastRow)

MyArray = rngTarget.Value

strg = Join(MyArray, Delim)
strg = Delim & strg

For Each cel In rngSource
    If InStr(1, strg, Delim & cel.Value & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then
    Else
    'Copy the row or range here
    End If

Next cel
```

End Sub

But now, I have one of two problems:

1. If I declare MyArray as string type I have problems loading values to array
2. If I declare MyArray as variant type I have problems in the Join

Can anyone help-me please??

Comment: Can you add some sample data? It will help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are these actual Excel Tables or just areas of data?

Comment: They are simple examples of Excel Tables, just to simplify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use Either Collection object, or Dictionary Object. These objects help a lot when you try to find the unique records.

Let us take an example, We have two sheets: Source and Target.

You need to loop through Column A in both sheets and move the data from Source Worksheet to target Worksheet. Following is the code, not tested, but it should do the trick. I have added comments so you can easily understand and fit this in your situation easily

```
Dim ids As Collection


Sub MoveData()


   On Error GoTo MoveData_Error

    Set ids = New Collection

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim idRange As Range

    Dim cell As Range




    Set sourceRange = Range("A1:A100") 'assign your source range here. Code will try to pick ID in this range, and check in ID Range
    Set idRange = Range("A1:A100") ' assign your target range here. Code will find the ID in this range


    'load all ids from target range in the collection.

    On Error Resume Next ' suppressing the error if any duplicate value is found

    For Each cell In idRange.Cells
            ids.Add cell.Value, cell.Value ' adding in collection to maintain a unique collection
            Err.Clear
    Next cell

    On Error GoTo MoveData_Error


    'now I have information about all the availabe IDs in id collection. Now I will loop through to check


    For Each cell In sourceRange
        If ShouldCopy(cell) Then
            'write your code to copy
        End If
    Next cell


   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

MoveData_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure MoveData of VBA Document Sheet1"

End Sub


Public Function ShouldCopy(cell As Range) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo ShouldCopy_Error
    If cell.Value = "" Or IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit Function

    ids.Add cell.Value, cell.Value ' if error occurs here, then it means the id has been already moved or found in the ID worksheet range
    ShouldCopy = True
   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

ShouldCopy_Error:
    ShouldCopy = False
End Function
```

If you face any issues in understanding and need any help, please let me know.

Thanks,
V

Comment: I'm sorry but we have same kind of problem in ShouldCopy Function. Nothhing haappen's. If I ignore 'On Error GoTo ShouldCopy_Error' it give's me the message box in the 'MoveData_Error:'

Comment: After studying more something about collections, I try adding item to collection without key (only `ids.Add cell.Value`), and it gives me no more error (error 13 type mismatch). At the same time now it can't recognize what IDs I have in the target table. Any help?

Comment: I fix it converting key into a string - `ids.Add cell.Value, Cstr(cell.Value)`. Tank you by your help!

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't have sufficient time to go through your comments this weekend. Glad you resolved your problem yourself. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookup to your source data flagging each record as either present or absent and then bounce your macro off of that column (i.e only move it into target if the lookup = absent).

Comment: Thank you Tim, but I'd like to avoid formulas. My idea would be to load an array IDs of the target table, and in the source table compare each ID if exists in Array. If don't exist copy the row. Is it possible? Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes but I'm not near a machine where I can supply you with code at present; it involves loading an array with valus in the target table and then using a New Collection to compare values in the source against values in the array.  As a quick and dirty workaround, why not copy everything across and then use a macro to remove all duplicates?

Comment: There are other issues that do not allow me to do so. On the other hand, can get there with the code I post in question ?